# Updating an Image as a background of a Jpanel Only works once?

Tags: java, swing

I have the following code I found on this website. The code allows me to draw an image as the background of a JPanel. The issue I have is being able to update said image. The method I created is at the bottom and basically follows the code of the constructor but I cannot figure out why calling this code will not update my image after once use.

Basically using the setImg method only works the first time and thats it. If I call it again it does nothing.

Here is how I create the object

```
ImagePanel panel1 = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("src/title.png").getImage());
```

Here is how I am attempting to update it.

```
panel1.setImg(new ImageIcon("src/red.png").getImage());
```

Here is my object

```
import java.awt.Dimension; import java.awt.Graphics; import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon; import javax.swing.JPanel;

class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

      /**    *       */     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    private Image img;

      public ImagePanel(String img) {
        this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());      }

      public ImagePanel(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
        Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setMinimumSize(size);
        setMaximumSize(size);
        setSize(size);
        setLayout(null);      }

      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);     }

    public void setImg(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
        System.out.println("Img Set success");
        Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setMinimumSize(size);
        setMaximumSize(size);
        setSize(size);
        setLayout(null);    }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `repaint()` on the JPanel after changing its image so that it will draw the new image. Other problems:

- Your paintComponent method needs to call the `super.paintComponent(g)` method on its first line in order to do "house-keeping" painting and to remove "dirty" pixels.
- You're using null layouts -- shame on you.
- Your indentation and code formatting is non-standard. This will make it hard for others (us) to understand your code and be able to help you. Learn and follow standard formatting rules.
- If the JPanel is only going to show images and not hold components, then you're far better off using a JLabel and simply swapping ImageIcons.